# t sql query returns duplicate values

Tags: t-sql

I know this is an often asked question, but I've tried to resolve this myself and could not.

I've got 2 tables to join and now it's returning a duplicate value from the right table.

```
select am.Journal
,am.EntryNumber
,am.PayInvoice
,am.PayDiscAllowed
,am.PayTaxAmtDisc
,am.PayGrossPayment
,tm.*
from CshJnlPay am right join
(select 
Invoice
,SUM(NetSalesValue) as NetSalesValue
,SUM(DiscValue) as DiscValue
,SUM(TaxValue) as TaxValue
,SUM(QtyInvoiced) as QtyInvoiced
from Salesdetail
group by Invoice) tm
on am.PayInvoice = tm.Invoice
where Invoice = 'C90831'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query returns 2 rows with the same data from the right table then you have 2 rows in the left table with the same invoice number... 
You should check the left table with this query

Select * from CshJnlPay where PayInvoice = 'C90831'

You should get two rows.

Comment: Thanks,  how do I prevent this?

Comment: You can not prevent this... Is it possible that there are 2 rows in the left table with the same invoice number? If yes, then you will always get the same data from the right table if you use a join. Can you post an example from the data and tell me what you would like it to show? Maybe there is another way you can select the data